# View Dosen't resize after call view.setY(float number) and view.setTranslationY(float number) in android

Tags: android, scroll

I want to change the size or move during user scroll RecyclerView

There is `LinearLayout` And `RecyclerView` in Android

I need to change LinearLayout height size during RecyclerView Scrolled, So
On `RecyclerView` -> `setOnScrollListener` -> `onScrolled` i tried this code :

```
            if (!defined) {
                toolbarHeight = ll_header.getMeasuredHeight();
                footerHeight = ll_footer.getMeasuredHeight();
                defined = true;
            }
            toolbarOffset += dy;

            if(toolbarOffset > toolbarHeight){
                toolbarOffset = toolbarHeight;
            }
            if(toolbarOffset < 0){
                toolbarOffset = 0;



            }

            ll_header.setY(-1 * toolbarOffset);
            ll_header.requestLayout();

            recycler_view.requestLayout();
```

[image]

Comment: I don´t understand this maybe...but setY() sets the y position of a view, but you want to change the size...why setY() ? Is this a programmatically generated LinearLayout?

Comment: i want to change the size or move during user scroll RecyclerView .

Comment: usually you´ll have to do it with the layoutParams.